# How to add custom php field views that returns my custom functions value?

Tags: views, 8

I'm designing a form that creates a user on sign in. After that I'm displaying the data in a view for an admin to approve. I need to add custom PHP code that calls a function that performs approval of users. How can I do that?

In D7, we can add **Global:views PHP** field to custom php code.
Likewise I need that in D8 also.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes in d7 we had php but in d8 (for good reason) this is not the case. You can however create a controller to do the approval functionality,

then in the view create a button or link that passes the user id to it

such as in view make sure you have the user id field then 
make a new filed with custom text

```
<a href="/your-controller-path-to-approve-user/{{uid}}>Approve user</a>
```

then in a custom module create a controller  see:

1) https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-a-basic-controller

2) https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-routing-file

then change the route to use your path and better permission

yourmodule.content:

path: '/your-controller-path-to-approve-user/{user_id}'

....

_permission: 'Administer users'

then in your controller method 
example

```
   public function content($user_id) {
     //do the stuff to approve the user here.
   }
```

for bonus points you can look in to making it use ajax. eg 
https://api.drupal.org/comment/62725#comment-62725

and if this is still not your thing then you will need to look in to

creating custom Twig extensions but far better to go the controller route.

Comment: Thanks Taggart. It worked perfectly!!